# Why relative static call not implement namespace of extended class?

Tags: php, namespaces, extends

Why only static call return 2?

it seems to me that a class call not by absolute name should depend on the current namespace in the class

```
<?php
namespace A {
    class B {
        static function test(){
            echo 1;
        }
        static function check(){
            B::test();//1 why?
            self::test();//1
            static::test();//2
        }
    }
}
namespace B {
    class B extends \A\B {
        static function test(){
            echo 2;
        }
    }
}
namespace {
    B\B::check();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`B::test()` is executed inside the `A` namespace and therefore takes the `B` class, that is provided by the `A` namespace. Therefore `A\B::test` is called. The context of the current class is not relevant for that.

The following example shows, that the heredity is irrelevant for this behavior.

```
<?php
namespace A {
    class B {
        static function test() {
             echo 3;
        }
    }
    class A {
        static function test(){
            echo 1;
        }
        static function check(){
            B::test();//3
            self::test();//1
            static::test();//2
        }
    }
}
namespace B {
    class B extends \A\A {
        static function test(){
            echo 2;
        }
    }
}
namespace {
    B\B::check();
}
```

`static::test` returns `2` eventhough you are in the `A` namespace, because `static` takes the context from the calling super class and not the current namespace.

`self::test` returns `1`, because `self` takes the context of the current class instead of the super class.